# Environment variables in Postman

Tags: environment-variables, postman

I'm using Postman v7.23.0 and I have a kind of problem with the environment variables. I've set token to be saved in an env variable, It gets value each time but when I use it as a Bearer Authentication It doesn't work. when I set the token in header authentication everything is fine. I'll appreciate any suggestions about the problem.

[Postman env variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtAo1.png)
[successful request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcLE9.png)

Comment: Show us the request that is successful

Comment: when I use the token directly in header authorization it works fine. I attached the successful request image to the question.

Comment: It might be an issue of upper case letter, could you pass **Bearer** instead of **bearer** and check?

Comment: Thanks but it should not be related because in the case of using  Postman environment variables, I choose Bearer Token in Type(first image) and when I directly give the token I type "bearer" in the header authorization which works fine.